# php REGEX for any matching possibilities?

Tags: php, regex, string, pattern-matching

In php, lets say i have 2 Groups of words to match:

Left Group:

1. stackover
2. overflow

Right Group:

- stackflow
- stack over flow
- over the stack flow

From the point of LEFT GROUP (by looping each), how do i write the regex pattern to say the entries inside.. are the similar matches for the entries in the RIGHT GROUP?

Answer (score 5):

I think that there is a better option in this case. There is a function called [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) which calculates distance between two strings - the minimal number of characters you have to replace, insert or delete to transform one string into another.

So you can just iterate through your arrays and find closest strings. There is a good example on the man page.